# How to get youTube featured-video URL using youTube API?

Tags: api, youtube

How can I get the youTube featured-video URL using the youTube API?

The youTube API example page seems fine:

developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_channel_search

On the sample page the href video under the `gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#featured-video` works fine and gives me a good href to a featured video, for example "bYKugypF8HA" gives the featured-video www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYKugypF8HA.

However, running the youTube API example today, the API no longer appears to return a good href for the featured-video, API call as follows:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/channels?q=soccer&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2&alt=json&prettyprint=true

In the result, there is the "link": "rel": "`http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#featured-video`", however, for example the href video "`AAAAAE-REqU`" is tagged by youTube "video not available" when I try to play it on youTube here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAAAAE9T36k

Comment: Might be related to this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/z0x1vmjTsP4. This is related video for a user, but maybe the root cause is the same.

Comment: Agreed (google api bug) TofferJ - feel free to mark as a solution and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related video for a user is currently missing in the YouTube API. Bug has been reported. You can follow the progress here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/z0x1vmjTsP4.